# Computing line equations of two crossing tangents

Tags: computational-geometry, linear-programming

[image]

Pictured is the problem in question. How do I compute the line equations for these two crossing tangents? These lines happen to be supporting two point sets for two convex hulls.

Comment: Forget convex hulls. Each of the two lines can be thought of as a half-plane. Try to come up with a parameterisation of the half-plane and a set of constraints which mean "every point in P is inside the half-plane and every point in Q is outside the half-plane". The solutions are the lines which separate P and Q. Then you just need to think about what constitutes "optimal".

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.