# Computing the line equations of two crossing tangents in a point set separated by a vertical line?

Tags: computational-geometry, linear-programming

[image]

I have provided a picture as an example. We have two point sets, P and Q. P is to the left of this vertical line (named x = x0), and Q is to the right of it. The goal is to compute the line equations for both l1 and l2, as listed in the picture. My understanding is that this is a linear programming problem. The algorithm I'm looking for would run in O(n+m) time. I have only been able to find examples of O(n log n) time, and I'm not quite sure where else to look for O(n+m) time specifically.

Comment: Please don't [re-post old questions](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/71586/755) - instead, we'd prefer that you edited the old question.  Also, the comments there remain applicable: [1](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/71586/computing-line-equations-of-two-crossing-tangents?noredirect=1#comment153316_71586), [2](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/71586/computing-line-equations-of-two-crossing-tangents?noredirect=1#comment153331_71586).  Can you describe your O(n log n) time algorithm in the question?